# how to bind dropdownlist in view dynamically ? mvc4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to replace this code in my view

**Code :**

```
<label for="name">Lead Source</label><select name="Lead_Source" id="Lead_Source" rel="2">
                                        <option value="1">News Papers </option>
                                        <option value="2">Internet</option>
                                        <option value="3">Social networking</option>
                                         <option value="4">Others</option>
                                        </select>
```

I want to replace with Dropdownlist so I will bind data dynamically by I am getting undone by work .

**I tried like this:**

```
<label for="name">Lead Source</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(c=>c.Lead_Source, Model.Lead_Source_List,"--Select Source--");
```

**The error i am getting after i replace static code is**

```
 CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Ibs.Iportal.Iwise.Web.Models.LeadSortModel>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, object)' has some invalid arguments
```

EDIT : I am passing a model to view which contain a Lead_Source_List of enumerable list data

Regards

Comment: did u try  `@Html.DropDownList()`

Comment: ty for reply and now i got my answer . Just small conversion issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create a view model and make strongly typed view,do something like this in you action:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(int id)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    using (var db = new SomeDataContext())
    {
        // Get the boxer you would like to edit from the database
        model.Boxer = db.Boxers.Single(x => x.BoxerId == id);

        // Here you are selecting all the available weight categroies
        // from the database and projecting them to the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
        model.WeightCategories = db.WeightCategories.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.WeightCategoryId.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        })
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

this chunk is populating select list item:

```
model.WeightCategories = db.WeightCategories.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.WeightCategoryId.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            })
```

and assigned to model

Now use in view this way:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => model.Boxer.CurrentWeightCategory.WeightCategoryId,
    Model.WeightCategories
)
```

Comment: Although i got my answer before you posted . I marked your answer becoz your explanation is cool n apt to current my question . Ty for your time